# Typescript + React, rendering an array from a stateless functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, definitelytyped

The React team [announced](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html) that since React 16:

> You can now return an array of elements from a component’s render method.

This works in typescript for regular class components, but I cannot get it to work for stateless functional components.

See [this repo](https://github.com/edorivai/ts-sfc-array) if you want to reproduce for yourself.

Code:

```
import * as React from 'react';

// See this example working in a non-TS environment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ppl3wopo8j
class Hello extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>
        <Foo />
        <Bar /> {/* Error: 'JSX element type 'Element[]' is not a constructor function for JSX elements. */}
      </div>;
    }
}

class Foo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return [<div>foo</div>, <div>fooz</div>];
    }
}

function Bar() {
    // Cannot render an array from a SFC
    return [<div>bar</div>, <div>baz</div>];
}
```

Building this snipper results in the following error:

```
'JSX element type 'Element[]' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Property 'render' is missing in type 'Element[]'.'
```

As you can see, rendering an array from a regular class component works, but it fails when rendering an array from a stateless functional component.

I'm unsure whether the problem lies with my code/setup, the DefinitelyTyped react types, or with typescript itself.

Answer (score 4):

Until the open [Definitely Typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/20356#issuecomment-336384210) issue has been resolved, the best work around is probably just to use `<React.Fragment/>` instead.  For functional purposes, I don't *think* there is any difference:

```
const Bar: React.SFC<CheckoutProps> = (props) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>bar</div>
      <div>baz</div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: Note `SFC` and `StatelessComponent` are deprecated in React 17. The deprecation notice suggests users use `FunctionComponent` or `FC` instead.

Answer (score -3):

"You can now return an array of elements from a component’s **render** method."

The array of JSX is being compiled by React.Components **render** method. A stateless functional component lacks that render method.

You could either wrap your array of elements in a parent div instead of the array or use a regular class component.

Comment: No. You can return arrays even from stateless functional components. See example: https://codepen.io/pawelgrzybek/pen/WZEKWj

Comment: Thanks for the note.  Looks like it was a type error.

Answer (score -4):

You can suppress the error and have your code working by casting your component as `any`:

```
const Bar: any = () => [<div>bar</div>, <div>baz</div>]
```

Comment: Yeah, I know how to suppress or work around the issue ;). I raised this question hoping to either surface a TS/React bug, or learn about how I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: It seems it's neither, but an open issue in `DefinitelyTyped`. See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/20356#issuecomment-336384210

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, my Google skills have failed me! Thanks, Dane