# JSX element type 'Element[]' is not a constructor function for JSX elements

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created a `LinkArray` component. When I want to use it, I get this error:

> JSX element type '`Element[]`' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
>
> Type '`Element[]`' is missing the following properties from type '`Element`': `type`, `props`, `key`

Why can't I use the component?

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Please include your code as text, not an image

Comment: `array` is supposed to be an array of property objects. Whatever you are passing is not an array.

Comment: I dropped the files in github,This is an array of objects, see for yourself. 
 https://github.com/vzgo0022/Error/blob/master/src/components/Nav/Nav.tsx

Comment: why type the response? why not let typescript determine the type of the result? I'm pretty sure the Link elements are not of type `JSX.Element` but of type `Component`

Comment: I'm sure that the LinkArray component returns exactly an array of JSX.Element [] objects,when I delete JSX.Element [] I see that the VSC automatically pastoes LinkArray returns JSX.Element [],And even if I delete JSX.Element the error does not change

Comment: See [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53718997/1136235)

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53718997/1136235). It probably hasn't been fixed.

Comment: React.SFC outdated  https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1057625147216220162 ,  As I understand it is now important to write code   https://codesandbox.io/s/3xzqjk6rrp